# Take value execute class string

Tags: php, function, class

I have class for take values inside loop as this :

`$db_user->take_phone[1];`

Inside loop I need take different values for the class

```php
$a=array("phone","name","street");

foreach($a as $aa) {
    echo $db_user->take_'$aa.'[1]
}
```

As you can see inside the loop I need to change the value inside `take_$string`, but it doesn't work. I suppose there is a syntax error but I'm not sure. How can I write this to work correctly.

I've tried different ways but haven't found a solution.

Comment: This is possible, but it is a very bad style. There are only extremely rare occasions where such an approach actually is required. Instead you should indeed explicitly implement the actual statements. Typically the number of such attributes is not of such an exceeding amount that this is not possible.

Comment: You really should not assume all the things you assume. It has not been me who downvoted your question, so please don't accuse me. And after having worked for some 25 years in the business I am pretty sure I know how php string evaluation works. I tried to help, but apparently you are not interested in that. Fine with me, good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [variable variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), which takes the form of `$var->$property`. Notice the extra `$`.

```php
$a = array("phone","name","street");

foreach($a as $aa) {
    $var = "take_$aa";
    echo $db_user->$var[1];
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/HolHZ

Comment: @Fran, can you explain why this doesn't work? Further, I'm not that one that downvoted you, but that often happens when it is hard to read a question and/or there's not enough for us to troubleshoot. It would greatly help if you provide sample data that you are starting with, along with what you want for output.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors php syntax. I has explained it in my example more:

```php
<?php
$db_user  = new stdClass();
$db_user->take_phone = [
    'p1','p2','p3'
];
$db_user->take_name = [
    'n1','n2','n3'
];
        
$db_user->take_street = [
    's1','s2','s3'
];  
    
$a=array("phone","name","street");

foreach($a as $aa) {
    echo $db_user->{'take_'.$aa}[1];
}
```

Comment: No have errors  you don´t read nothing because my question is about how write right the function and use but you don´t read me and you tell write errors when my question it´s about how write this